# How does this bit of code work? Someone said this is a solution

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
frame.buttons = {}
frame.AddButton = function()
    frame.buttons[#frame.buttons + 1] = frame:Add("DButton")
    local button = frame.Buttons[#frame.buttons] 
end
```

I know it's simple, but it's the only part so far that I do not understand.
How do you add now buttons and how do you access them?

Comment: I think you should describe your question better, because just throwing code doesn't help too much.

Answer (score 0):

This code adds a button to a [Frame](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Frame) instance. It also creates a list of buttons in that Frame. You need to replace that `"DButton"` by a [DButton](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/DButton) instance.

Ideally you change the code like that:

```
frame.buttons = {}
frame.AddButton = function(button)
    frame.buttons[#frame.buttons + 1] = frame:Add(button)
    local button = frame.Buttons[#frame.buttons] 
end
```

If you want to add a button, create it, then call `frame.AddButton(myButton)`.